# EntityDataSource need to make it lower or upper case

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have **EntityDataSource** with **GridView**, is there any way to make the data in **EntityDataSource** to be lower or upper case? **EntityDataSource** not allowed function for example:

`Select="lower(it.[Name])"`

this lower function is not recognize in **EntityDataSource** or any other function, so I found something in EntityDataSource **OnQueryCreated** which we can write LINQ but how I can make it lower? any ideas? this is my code for **EntityDataSource**:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="etsCaseUser" runat="server" 
                  ConnectionString="name=****" 
                  DefaultContainerName="****" 
                  EnableFlattening="False" 
                  AutoGenerateWhereClause="False"
                  CommandText="select ui.[USER_ID], it.[CR_ID], it.[JOB_TITLE], it.[ADMISSION_DATE]
                                from CASE_REVIEWS as it, USERS as ui where it.[SUBMITTED_BY] LIKE ui.[USER_ID]"
                                OrderBy="it.[CR_ID]">
```

Comment: can you please show some code.

Comment: I updated, I want to make for example **JOB_TITLE** to be lower or upper case or all fields doesn't matter

Comment: I think there is no support of some function in EntityDataSource.

Comment: You can create a view and query that view in `EntityDataSource`

Comment: @MairajAhmad Yes I know I mention that, but maybe there are another way to make it! I have one solution is to deal with LINQ so I can do lower case but how I can do it?

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid I don't understand, do you have any code about what you say?